The permutations Easy to determine the parity but Hard to decompose
In A.I.Kostrikin's Exercises in Algebra, there is a question as follows:
306.Determine the parity of the permutations:
e)
$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdots & n-1 & n\\
2 & 4 & 6 & \cdots & 1 & 3 & 5 & \cdots & \cdot & \cdot\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$;
h)
$
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1 & n\\
n & 1 & n-1 & 2 & \cdots & \cdots\ &\cdots\\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$.
The answer for 306.e is already here.
But our teacher decided to strengthen this question :
"Decompose the permutations into a product of disjoint cycles AND THEN determine the parity."
He seems to want us to solve the strengthened question first!!!
Even the teaching assistant cannot solve it either! (It has been ten years since the question was left for practice.)
Theorem has it that "Any permutation can be decomposed into the product of disjoint cycles.", but it did not tell us how to construct it.
Since we can determine the parity(existence), can we really decompose them(constructibility)?
Added:
"Decompose the permutations into a product of disjoint cycles" requires the number of cycles and the element of each cycle are elementary functions
For example:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & \cdots & n-1 & n \\
n & n-1 & n-2&n-3&\cdots&2&1
\end{pmatrix}
The matrix can be decomposed to:
\begin{equation}
\prod \limits_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor}\begin{pmatrix}
i & n+1-i\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The number of cycles and the element of each cycle are all linear functions(elementary functions), and there is a classification about parity.

It is straighforward to write the cycle decomposition. Start with $1$, see what it maps to, see what that maps to, and continue until you cycle back to $1$. Then take the first number that you have not yet listed (if any) and repeat the process. Keep going until you have written what happens to every number.

If needed, experiment with relatively small values of $~n.$

@ArturoMagidin We are trying to find a general formula. A construction method is always feasible, but does not mean that a formula can always be found.

You literally asked how to decompose them "constructively". Now you complain that you were given a feasible construction method instead of a general formula... which you did not ask for. Did you even try? Or are you just hoping that someone here will solve it for you since your TA proved incapable?

@ArturoMagidin It is that TA proved incapable, which means that a "formula" cannot be found even the "method" is right.
